Java Springboot JWT: Problem accessing the /authenticate path. I get a 403 code back
I am writing some basic code to incorporate JWT into my simple Java Springboot application. The problem is that when I launch the request to http://localhost:8081/authenticate with the next JSON body, I get a 403 code back:
{
    "username":"usuario",
    "password":"pass"
}

I attach the different classes I have implemented in case you can see where my mistake is.
SecurityConfig
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    private final JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    public SecurityConfig(JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter) {
        this.jwtRequestFilter = jwtRequestFilter;
    }
     
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/authenticate", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/swagger-ui/**", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}

AuthRequest
@Data
public class AuthRequest {
    private String username;
    private String password;
}

Any help is welcome! Thank you

there is much other configuration to add, i assume you have configured jwt and your service , can you provide the rest of the code

You have to do these steps:

Check the Endpoint:Ensure you have a /authenticate endpoint in your controller that uses AuthenticationManager to authenticate users. For example:
@PostMapping("/authenticate")
public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody AuthRequest authRequest) throws Exception {
authenticationManager.authenticate(
new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authRequest.getUsername(), authRequest.getPassword())
);
}

Configure AuthenticationManager:Verify that AuthenticationManager is set up correctly. For testing, you might want to use in-memory authentication like this:
@Autowired
public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
.withUser("usuario").password(passwordEncoder().encode("pass")).roles("USER");
}

JWT Utility:Ensure your JwtUtil class is properly generating and validating JWT tokens.

Request Format: Make sure your request includes Content-Type: application/json and that the JSON body is formatted correctly.

Check Logs:enter code hereReview application logs for any authentication errors or warnings.


